# c# how to add a line break to a memory stream

Tags: c#, .net

I am merging 3 files, for example, but at final there are not line breaks between the files...

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
File.OpenRead("c:\file1.txt").CopyTo(m);
File.OpenRead("c:\file2.txt").CopyTo(m);
File.OpenRead("c:\file3.txt").CopyTo(m);
m.Position = 0;
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(m).ReadToEnd());
```

how can I may add a line break to a memory stream?

Comment: Just write one to the steam. Use `Write` to write the `\n` character between each `CopyTo`

Comment: Define "line break" in the context of which characters and which encoding. Presumably, the files use the same encoding and possibly have line breaks that you'd want to match. Why are you reading text files as bytes, anyway? But then you are using a UTF8 StreamReader! Are the files UTF8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
File.OpenRead("c:\file1.txt").CopyTo(m);
m.WriteByte(0x0A);                // this is the ASCII code for \n line feed
                                  // You might want or need \n\r in which case you'd 
                                  // need to write 0x0D as well.
File.OpenRead("c:\file2.txt").CopyTo(m);
m.WriteByte(0x0A);
File.OpenRead("c:\file3.txt").CopyTo(m);
m.Position = 0;
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(m).ReadToEnd());
```

But as @usr points out, you really should think about the encoding.

Comment: `(byte)'\n'` seems cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

You can write the line break to the stream. You need to decide which one you want. Probably, you want `Encoding.Xxx.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine)`. You also need to decide which encoding to use (which must match the encoding of the other files).

Since the line break string is ASCII what matters is only the distinction between single-byte encodings and ones that use more. Unicode uses two bytes per newline char for example.

If you need to guess you probably should go with UTF 8 without BOM.

You also can try a fully text based approach:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(a) + Environment.NewLine + File.ReadAllLines(b);
```

Let me also point out that you need to dispose the streams that you open.

Comment: tks, but i need even a stream

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the encoding, for example `UTF-8`, you can do:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Do stuff ...
    var newLineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
    ms.Write(newLineBytes, 0, newLineBytes.Length);
    // Do more stuff ... 
}
```